# Non deprecated GCM Cloud Endpoints example 2016

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-endpoints

Last year when you added a Cloud Endpoints plus GCM module to an Android Studio project, the IDE created some sample code both in the `backend` and the `app` that showed how to use GCM with Cloud Endpoints.

However, with the newer versions of Android Studio you only get the `backend` part added for you. So I went back into my old projects and dug up some of the convenient `app` code which registered, and sent GCM push notifications in Android.

Here is what that code looks like:

`GcmBroadcastReceiver.java`

```
public class GcmBroadcastReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
        ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
                GcmIntentService.class.getName());
        // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
        startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
        setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

    }
}
```

`GcmIntentService.java`

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

    android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder notification;

    public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
        // The getMessageType() intent parameter must be the intent you received
        // in your BroadcastReceiver.
        String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);

        if (extras != null && !extras.isEmpty()) {  // has effect of unparcelling Bundle
            // Since we're not using two way messaging, this is all we really to check for
            if (GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {
                Logger.getLogger("GCM_RECEIVED").log(Level.INFO, extras.toString());

                showToast(extras.getString("message"));
                sendNotification(extras.getString("message"));

            }
        }

        //call to the API and get new data.

        GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }

    protected void showToast(final String message) {
        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void sendNotification(String msg) {
        notification = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        //set number of notifications count
        //notification.setNumber(x);
        //cancels notification when app is opened.
        notification.setAutoCancel(true);
        //build the notification
        notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.greenicon);
        notification.setTicker("This is the ticker!");
        //set time
        notification.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
        notification.setContentTitle("New message!");
        notification.setContentText(msg);
        notification.setSound((Settings.System.DEFAULT_NOTIFICATION_URI));
        //LED
        notification.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);
        // intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        //give phone access to perform this intent b/c they may be in another part of their phone.
        //aka gives phone access to the intents in our app
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
        //what to do when notification is clicked:
        notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        //Builds notification and issues it (sends it to device). Can build and send out notifcations
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        //send out notification with uniqueID
        nm.notify(2158, notification.build());
    }
}
```

`GcmRegistrationAsyncTask`

```
class GcmRegistrationAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
    private static Registration regService = null;
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    private Context context;

    // TODO: change to your own sender ID to Google Developers Console project number, as per instructions above
    private static final String SENDER_ID = "1026567774990";

    public GcmRegistrationAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (regService == null) {
            Registration.Builder builder = new Registration.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
                    new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
                    // Need setRootUrl and setGoogleClientRequestInitializer only for local testing,
                    // otherwise they can be skipped
                    .setRootUrl("https://push-notif-45657747.appspot.com/_ah/api/")
                    .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                        @Override
                        public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest)
                                throws IOException {
                            abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                        }
                    }) ;
            // end of optional local run code

            regService = builder.build();
        }

        String msg = "";
        try {
            if (gcm == null) {
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
            }
            String regId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
            msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regId;

            // You should send the registration ID to your server over HTTP,
            // so it can use GCM/HTTP or CCS to send messages to your app.
            // The request to your server should be authenticated if your app
            // is using accounts.
            regService.register(regId).execute();

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            msg = "Error: " + ex.getMessage();
        }
        return msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Logger.getLogger("REGISTRATION").log(Level.INFO, msg);
    }
}
```

However, I am getting some deprecated errors in Android Studio now:

`gcm.register(SENDER_ID);` is deprecated and so is `GoogleCloudMessaging.MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE`.

This GCM stuff is pretty confusing to begin with and while there is some information [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/legacy-regid) on how to use it, I was wondering if anyone had any currently working non-deprecated examples or maybe you could suggest some edits to the above code if you know what you are doing...? Much thanks!

Comment: You can read this [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/c2dm#history) on how to migrate from C2DM to GCM. In C2DM, the Sender ID is an email address. In GCM, the Sender ID is a project number that you acquire from the API console. Check this [example](https://github.com/google/gcm) which might help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to give people a little guide here in case they were lost.

First check out and stay up to date with this Google Cloud Messaging Android example:

https://github.com/google/gcm

To make it work you will have to generate a `google-services.json` file which you can do here: 
https://developers.google.com/mobile/add

Make sure you are logged into the google developers console before you go that link. It will load your projects for you and automatically set up the gcm api key for you in your projects credentials.

Copy/paste the `google-services.json` into the `/app` directory of your Android project.

Add a cloud endpoints with gcm module to the android project.

Enter your gcm api key (which you can view on your credentials page on developers console) into the `webapp-WEB_INF/appengine-web.xml` file in your cloud endpoints backend:

`<property name="gcm.api.key" value="your-api-key-here"/>`

This way, inside the Android client and `MessagingEndpoint` the code will automatically get the api key (in the endpoint it will be the line `Sender sender = new Sender(API_KEY);` for example, which will just retrieve it for you).

Run the sample gcm android project and it should work. Send a push notification with the API's explorer you deployed.

BIG NOTE: when you are ready to use the sample code in your own app make sure the `RegistrationIntentService` is in the root of your package or it won't work! Took a while to figure that out... Not sure if it is a bug or what.